# Using modelica fluid library for elastic pipes

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I would like to use the Modelica.Fluid library to model flow in blood vessels where the diameter of the vessel (and thus flow resistance and fluid volume) is a function of the internal and ambient pressures, as well as control inputs. Is there any way to make the diameter and cross sectional area of the *dynamic pipe* models (and the chain of base classes) variables rather than parameters, or would that "break" the core assumptions of the Fluid library? If this was possible, the reversing flow, enthalpy flow, and trace component flow features would be very useful in modeling physiological systems -  capabilities not available in the Modelica  Physiolibrary.

Comment: Are you aware of the [PhysioLibrary](https://github.com/MarekMatejak/Physiolibrary)? They have some models for veins and arteries.

Comment: Also, see https://github.com/physiology and http://www.physiomodel.org/

Answer (score 3):

In general in Modelica you cannot just change a parameter to a continuous-time variable - or bind a parameter to a continuous-time variable.

The reason is that the equations may have to be adapted to the changes - with a parameter "V" you can interchangeably write `der(V*rho)` or `V*der(rho)`, but for a continuous-time variable "V" only one of those formulations is correct.

Thus it should not be possible in Modelica to circumvent that.

So a direct answer is: No, there should not be a way.
However, what might be possible would be to rewrite DynamicPipe (and some of its base-classes) to change diameter etc to be continuous-time variables - that may require changing some equations due to the issue above, and at least verifying that they are correct.

That variable-diameter DynamicPipe could be a direct replacement for the normal DynamicPipe - and in most cases it would be as efficient as the original one.

But I don't know how much work that would be.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I suspected I would have to start at the base classes and build from there.

Answer (score 0):

New version 3.0 of Physiolibrary will be based on Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.FluidPort compatible with Modelica.Fluid. Coming soon. See curent master branche https://github.com/MarekMatejak/Physiolibrary

Comment: Please, use link formatting: `[link](url)`